When is it right to tell someone they’re wrong in a harsh way
Do the rabbis say there a time and place when one should confront someone who is guilty of serious sin.  Say slander, adultery, etc.

It really, REALLY depends on the context. "Just as it is a mitzvah to speak up when you will be heard, it is a mitzvah to NOT speak up when you won't be."

The Torah says (Vayikra 19:17) הוכח תוכיח את עמיתך you should reprove your fellow, but, as @Shalom’s quote from the Gemara Yevamos 65b says, the situation must be carefully assessed before proceeding

Most likely when something irreversible and bad is about to occur unless a person stops.

... @YDJ and if your saying something will actually prevent it.
